# Problem with parsing html for meta tag (bs4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I parse htmls of structures from Protein Data Bank and one problem occurred: one of the things I want to extract from the htmls is a meta tag. 
This is example of that tag - important is, that the "content" is diferrent in different hmlts (thus I can't parse for exact text in content - that is the reason why I put blablah-text here):

```
<meta name="author" content="blahblah1, blahblah2, blahblah3">
```

I try to solve it with code:

```
with open(datafile) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(f.readlines()), "html.parser")
    tag = soup.find("meta", name="author").next_sibling
    print(tag.contents)
```

But it returs me error:

> TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'

I tried the code with `find_all` as well, the same error occurred. Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works with your datafile:

```
with open(datafile) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(f.readlines()), "html.parser")
    tag = soup.find("meta", attrs={'name': "author"})
    print(tag.attrs['content'])
```

---

Or you can use this code if 
datafile:

```
<meta name="author" content="content1">sdsd</meta>
<meta name="author" content="content2">sdsd</meta>
```

scripy.py:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
datafile='1.txt'
with open(datafile) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(f.readlines()), "html.parser")
    tag = soup.find("meta", attrs={'name': "author"}).findNext('meta')
    print(tag.attrs['content'])
```